# Join two dataframe and expand the dataframe with assign the ID

Tags: pandas, csv

I want to insert a dataframe into another dataframe with Time key with ID appear to follow the Time. How to do it?

my data looks like this:

```
df1
ID  Time
ID1 10:40
ID1 11:00
ID2 11:10
ID2 11:30

df2
Time    X   Y
10:40   45  50
10:50   55  55
11:00   65  60
11:10   75  65
11:20   85  70
11:30   95  75
```

my expected result looks like this:

```
ID  Time    X   Y
ID1 10:40   45  50
ID1 10:50   55  55
ID1 11:00   65  60
ID2 11:10   75  65
ID2 11:20   85  70
ID2 11:30   95  75
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with datetimes columns, last use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for convert it to `HH:MM` strings:

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'])

df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='Time').assign(Time = lambda x: x['Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
print (df)
    Time   X   Y   ID
0  10:40  45  50  ID1
1  10:50  55  55  ID1
2  11:00  65  60  ID1
3  11:10  75  65  ID2
4  11:20  85  70  ID2
5  11:30  95  75  ID2
```

Comment: is it possible without transform to datetime?

Comment: Another solution should be `df2.merge(df1, how='outer').ffill()`, but a bit dangerous - is necessary match always first rows, else bad assigned IDs. It depends of data.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I got `KeyError: 'Time'`. how about that?

Comment: @Arief What is `print (df1.columns.tolist())` and `print (df2.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: `['ID', 'Time']` and `['Time ', 'X', 'Y']`. Maybe because the type is `non-null object` after I did `df.info()`

Comment: @Arief - If chec second, then is traling space `'Time '`, so use `df2.columns = df2.columns.str.strip()`