# "right keys must be sorted" in join two column with key Time and assign ID

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, merge

based on my previous question

[Join two dataframe and expand the dataframe with assign the ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511588/join-two-dataframe-and-expand-the-dataframe-with-assign-the-id)

I have two dataframe looks like this:

```
 df1
 ID         Time
 ID_E   9:07:00
 ID_E   9:15:00
 ID_B   9:09:00
 ID_B   9:14:00

 df2 
 Time        X        Y
 9:07:00    767597  9427273
 9:08:00    767597  9427284
 9:09:00    767608  9427284
 9:10:00    767608  9427295
 9:11:00    767619  9427306
 9:12:00    767623  9427311
 9:13:00    767628  9427319
 9:14:00    767634  9427327
 9:15:00    767640  9427335
```

I want to insert a dataframe into another dataframe with Time key with ID appear to follow the Time. However, the results got error `right keys must be sorted` this because the time in `df1` not sorted. How to fix this condition?

I used this code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(data1.csv)
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip()
df2 = pd.read_csv(data2.csv)
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.strip()
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'])
df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='Time').assign(Time = lambda x: x['Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
df
```

My expected result:

```
  ID    Time         X        Y
  ID_E  9:07:00 767597  9427273
  ID_E  9:08:00 767597  9427284
  ID_E  9:09:00 767608  9427284
  ID_E  9:10:00 767608  9427295
  ID_E  9:11:00 767619  9427306
  ID_E  9:12:00 767623  9427311
  ID_E  9:13:00 767628  9427319
  ID_E  9:14:00 767634  9427327
  ID_E  9:15:00 767640  9427335
  ID_B  9:09:00 767608  9427284
  ID_B  9:10:00 767608  9427295
  ID_B  9:11:00 767619  9427306
  ID_B  9:12:00 767623  9427311
  ID_B  9:13:00 767628  9427319
  ID_B  9:14:00 767634  9427327
```

thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get:

> right keys must be sorted

Here are right keys column `df1.Time`, so necessary sorting by this column before `merge_asof`:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values('Time')
```

---

If error also need sorting by `df2.Time`:

> left keys must be sorted

```
df2 = df2.sort_values('Time')
```

All together:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(data1.csv)
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip()
df2 = pd.read_csv(data2.csv)
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.strip()
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'])
df1 = df1.sort_values('Time')

df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='Time').assign(Time = lambda x: x['Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get another error `('Unknown string format:', '0 days 09:07:00.000000000')`. Maybe because my data became `timedelta`. how about that?

Comment: @jezrael-this code `df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])`

Comment: @Arief - So be free omit `df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'])` and also `.assign(Time = lambda x: x['Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M'))`, it should working well, because timedeltas.

Comment: @jezrael-maybe this is a stupid question again. how to convert from timedeltas data example `0 days 09:07:00.000000000' to `09:07:00`.

Comment: if i omit that code. I got this `'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: @Arief - Not stupid question. But I have idea - first how working `df1['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['Time'])
df2['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df2['Time'])
df1 = df1.sort_values('Time')

df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='Time')` ?

Comment: @Arief - then in output if need convert timedeltas to strings use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51102096/2901002)